# Datastore BLOB that cannot be indexed

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a string (~180 chars length) as [datastore.ByteString](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#ByteString) type, I want it to be indexed so that I will able to filter by the type.

```
keys, err := datastore.NewQuery("User").
    Filter("SubscriptionToken= ", []byte(subscriptionToken)).Count(c)
```

When I'm trying to filter I'm getting this error:

```
{Service:"datastore_v3", Detail:"Property \"SubscriptionToken\" has a value meaning BLOB that cannot be indexed.", Code:1}
```

The only reason that I think about is that the size of the bytestring is greater than 1500k and it can't be indexed?

But I can't figure out how to check the bytestring size.

**UPDATE:**  this is how i insert the **User** entity

```
type User struct {
    UserEmail         string
    SubscriptionToken datastore.ByteString
}
//subscriptionToken has value
u := User{
            UserEmail:         userEmail,
            SubscriptionToken: datastore.ByteString(subscriptionToken),
        }

k := datastore.NewKey(c, "User", userKey, 0, nil)
        _, err = datastore.Put(c, k, &u)
        if err != nil {
            log.Debugf(c, "Write datastore.Put: %#v ", err)
            return err
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the `User` entity that you have in your Datastore has a property `SubscriptionToken` which is not of type `ByteString` but rather `[]byte`.

Properties of type `[]byte` are not indexed.

If you want a property of type Byte slice to be indexed, when you save the entity, the property must have a value of type [`datastore.ByteString`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#ByteString), for example:

```
type User struct {
    SubscriptionToken datastore.ByteString
}

u := User{SubscriptionToken: datastore.ByteString("somevalue")}
// Save u
key, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "User", nil), &u)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

`datastore.ByteString` is basically just a byte slice (`[]byte`) and nothing more (at the moment): it signals that you want the the byte slice that is being saved to be indexed.

And when you try to filter by this property, the property value to filter by has to be a value of type `[]byte`:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("User").Filter("SubscriptionToken=", []byte(subscriptionToken))

// If you want to count:
count, err := q.Count(c)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}

// Query/filter:
var users []*User
keys, err := q.GetAll(c, &users)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

Btw to check the length of a `ByteString` value, you can simply use the builtin function [`len()`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) since a `ByteString` is a byte slice (`[]byte`):

```
length := len(u.SubscriptionToken)
```

Comment: now im getting this error
datastore.NewQuery returned error:&errors.errorString{s:"datastore: bad query filter value type: unsupported datastore value type: datastore.ByteString"}

Comment: this ByteString(subscriptionToken))  has to be  datastore.ByteString(subscriptionToken) in order to compile ??

Comment: @MIkCode Ok, I tried the code, when filtering, you have to specify a value of type `[]byte`. The posted code now works.

Comment: im still getting the same error ,the bytestring is saved in the datastore as Blob , why ?
It might be a version "thing" ?

Comment: @MIkCode If you already have entities saved as `[]byte`, they will not miraculously change to `ByteString`. You have to load them and resave them as `ByteString`.

Comment: i drop the table completely re insert the data  as you can see in the update , but still datastore  set the type to BLOB  http://imgur.com/Lo87STS

Comment: @MIkCode I suggest you to upgrade/use the latest AppEngine SDK. I also suggest to clear your whole local datastore upon start. You can do that with `goapp serve -clear_datastore`